# Something like "common factor in evidence" , in portuguese

Tags: tikz-arrows

Im trying to display something like this in my article:
[image]

But, even i tried a lot, i couldn't achieve anything like that. Could any of you help me?

Comment: Please accept the provided answer since it obviously solved the problem. Keep in mind that the people here can only answer the question based on the information that you provide.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Heres one way to do it using the `tikzmark` library and then adjusting node positions with the `calc` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \[
        (\tikzmark{a}ax + \tikzmark{b}ay) = \tikzmark{c}a(x + y)
        \tikz[remember picture, overlay, baseline=0pt] {
            \draw[red, thick] ($(pic cs:a) + (0.1, 0.2)$) to[out=90, in=90] ($(pic cs:c) + (0.1, 0.2)$);
            \draw[red, thick] ($(pic cs:b) + (0.1, 0.2)$) to[out=90, in=90] ($(pic cs:c) + (0.1, 0.2)$);
        }
    \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works, thaks :)  but actually unformatted an other arrows scheme, which was also made with tikz :(

Comment: Glad I could help, this seems like a separate issue that would best be addressed in a new question